# Is there a way to make a dataframe in python from reading multiple excel files in which two properties are vectors and the others are doubles?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, vector

I'd like to create a dataframe in which there are different properties: "time", "signal", "speed", "weight".  
Specifically, "time" and "signal" should be column vectors with 1900 rows, but "speed" and "weight" are constants that i would like to store inside doubles. 
These variables are stored inside several excel files (one for each test performed) from which I could extract a dataframe by using

```
df = pandas.read_excel(fileExcel)
```

but after that I'd have multiple dataframes (one for each file) that have all properties that are column vectors with 1900 rows, so the properties that should be doubles are listed as column vectors with 1900 rows but with value NaN everywhere except for the first position.

What I'd like to obtain is a dataframe with all the test cases (so that it merges all of the data obtained from the excel file and stored in the dataframe `df`, each one as a single element of the dataframe), and each one has: "time" as a column vector of 1900 rows, "signal" as a column vector of 1900 rows, "speed" and "weight" as doubles with their values being read from the cell they are stored in, discarding all the NaN cells. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Please try out manipulating the data after the `read_excel` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do so by using **pandas.concat** and **.dropna**.

If you read in your Data:

```
df1= pd.read_excel()
df2= pd.read_excel()
df3= pd.read_excel()
df4= pd.read_excel()
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4], axis=1).dropna()
```

For how you want to drop them (Inplace=True or False) you should see the [pandas documentation on dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna).